# Sequelize multiple $or for different fields

Tags: sequelize.js, sequelize-typescript

Is there a way to create the query below using sequelize?
The main problem for me is to create multiple **OR** statements with different fields

```
WHERE "event"."active" = true

  AND ("event"."startDate" BETWEEN '2020-04-16' AND '2020-05-15' OR "event"."recurrenceEndDate" BETWEEN '2020-04-16' AND '2020-05-15')

  AND ("event"."parent" IS NULL OR "event"."independent" = true)
```

This is what I tried

```
where = {
    active: True,
    $or: [ 
          { startDate: { $between: [event.startDate, event.recurrenceEndDate] } },
          { recurrenceEndDate: { $between: [event.startDate, event.recurrenceEndDate] } }
         ]
    parent: { $is: null }

}
```

Now I need to add the `OR independent = true` inside `parent is null` statement, but I cant repeat the `$or` statement used before because it would be an invalid json (two fields with the same name)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this this:

```
where = {
  $and: [
    { active: True },
    { $or: [ 
          { startDate: { $between: [event.startDate, event.recurrenceEndDate] } },
          { recurrenceEndDate: { $between: [event.startDate, event.recurrenceEndDate]             } }
         ] },
   { $or: [ { parent: { $is: null } }, { independent: true }]
]
}
```

Comment: Yes, it did the trick! The "and" at first level was the key to solve the problem. Thank you a lot!